# Link 'title' attribute not mapping correctly in Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, links

I am using Glass.Mapper.Sc 4.3.4.197 and for some reason the "title" attribute ("Alternative Text" property of the link field in Sitecore; `Link.Title` property in Glass.Mapper) appears to not be mapping correctly.

I have a Sitecore link field that I am mapping to a glass model. I have set the "Alternative Text" property of the link field, and the destination. In my code, I have defined the property mapping to the link as follows:

```
public interface Foo
{
    ID ID { get; set; }
    ID TemplateID { get; set; }
    Link MyLink { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and I have mapped this property using the following fluent mapping:

```
Map(
    x =>
    {
        ImportMap<IBaseGlassModel>(); // maps ID and TemplateID properties
        x.AutoMap();
        x.Id(y => y.ID);
        x.TemplateId(FooConstants.TemplateId);
        x.EnforceTemplateAndBase();
        x.Field(y => y.MyLink).FieldType(SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink);
        ...
    });
```

Note that the link destination is coming through, as are all of the other fields and properties, but for some reason `Foo.MyLink.Title` is never set.

After noticing that the value wasn't being rendered, I debugged and found that the value was not being set for the property of `MyLink` on my glass model.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?